# Fluid Mechanics. How to nondimensionalize a variable with a power law index.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis

can anyone help me in nondimensionalizing these equation? I start from the equation in the first line. Using the nondimensional variable from the third line, I get the half-completed equation in the second line. The variables with the overbar has been nondimensionalized. As you can see, Im stuck in cancelling out the variables of U,a and Mu as there is a power of m there. m is actually the power law index, so i assume it has no dimension. Im just wondering if it is possible to just cancel them out without concerning the power m? Does the power m affects the dimension too?

Or is there any other way to do it? Feel free to ask me for more info. Thank you

[image: equation]

Comment: Because those variables have a dimension.. U is velocity, a is length and Mu is a viscosity..

Comment: The units of $w$ is that of $(a/\mu_H)$ times pressure to the $m$th power. Why should this equal the units of $U$ which you assume when you write $w/U$ ?

Comment: Because w is a velocity too.. a fluid velocity. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: The initial equation is dimensionally inconsistent. There is no value in nondimensionalising constants like $g$, and you haven't given scales for $p$ and $z$.

Comment: @Akimi You are missing the point. $w$ might be a velocity, but the right hand side of the $w$ equation does not have seem to have units of velocity. That is the problem!